# How to make the logo drop a bit in the nav menu and other suggestions

Tags: css, html

I am new to HTML and CSS but I am learning as I go.  I am trying to model my webpage after [this website](http://arcteryx.com/Home.aspx?language=EN#) for practice and right now I am mostly focused on the header.  I looked at the source code but the CSS file is unreadable since everything is clustered together when you open it.

I would like to figure out how to drop the logo down and make the black fill up the page so I don't see the background image any more than after the two images I have in the body.

This is my code for the header:

```
header {
    background-color:black;
    width:150%;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:1000px;
}
```

Here is my JSFiddle link to take a look at what i have so far. I did a bunch of copy pastes to fill the page out a bit so you could scroll. (I know its ugly but its not even close to being finished)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2f9R/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the background is concerned, you should remove your background div and add the following to your CSS:

```
background:url('http://stuffkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Ama-Dablam-Nepal.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
```

That should make the background cover the entire page nicely.

Now for the image going over the edge, you're going to need to set the height of your header to something less than your image height.  This should make the image overflow unless you specifically set it to hidden.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="http://www.tikkani.com/images/wolf_LOGO_WHITE.jpg" />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>           
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li> 
    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:-20px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-bottom:0;
    height:130px;
}
header ul{
    float:right;
}
header li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    height:110px;
}
header li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color:white;
}
header img {
    width:150px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uks3g/).  I cleaned up a few tags too.  Not that it's perfect.

UPDATE: Also fixed some of the header issues.  Some browsers add weird margins.  This should fix that. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46NaG/)

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much.  One thing I have to add is that I see you make the header li float right but if it floats left, it bumps the picture over.  I will try and play with the margins to see if that helps.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot I changed that!  You just need to float the image left too. http://jsfiddle.net/KL329/

Answer (score 0):

Removed this from html

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="http://stuffkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Ama-Dablam-Nepal.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
```

and add this to CSS

```
body{
    background-color:black;
}
```

Check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/d2f9R/7/

I am not clear about your logo question

Comment: I accidentally dragged and selected some content and I discovered this in yous JSFiddle: "<p>my name is bob and i have clothes so here is my website</p>" XD

Comment: Did you see the reference site?  That's what's being looked for with the logo.

Comment: That is totally fine thanks for the response! I want to include that background picture however similar to the way it is formatted on the Arcteryx site - when you scroll the bottom half of the page moves up and the picture seems to be scrolling as well.  The same goes with the logo question, if you see how it is formatted on the arcteryx nav bar, the logo drops a bit out of line with the menu options (shop, about, etc).